# Eclipse android project launch progress freezes

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing an android application and I'm experiencing a terrible problem. When I try to launch the application, the progress "Launching Project" doesn't finish! It just freezes and it even doesn't respond to cancel request. Needless to say, any other progress cannot be completed, therefor I even can't eclipse.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo, ADT V 21.1, SDK API Version 15 and Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what was the problem. Just re-installed ADT and everything is working fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ADT bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) instead. It may not help but they say we should use ADT Bundle.